# Laptop and 144 Hz External Monitor Compatibility

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have HP Omen Laptop with 1060 Max Q GPU.
Other Specs:-
https://www.cnet.com/products/omen-by-hp-15-ce198wm-15-6-core-i7-8750h-16-gb-ram-256-gb-ssd-plus-1-tb-hdd-us/?fbclid=IwAR2a5B4hdlwjfXarZpgH8IBiE4Ni_7g08xN7XnyPeDgzJmjdYg42VN9nhGw

Can someone help tell me if I can use an external 144 hz display monitor with my laptop and eventually making it 144 hz display. I don't have fps issues, it stays 200+ in the game i play. I have been searching if it would work but I couldnt find the answer needed! because some say it won't , some say it will, some say HDMI Port Version matters, some says there is no Version of HDMI port in laptops, some say DVI port is needed but my laptop has mini display port, also I didnt find my laptop hdmi port version online anywhere..Also to mention I only have Thunderbolt3, mini-display port and HDMI port, no DVI port. Please guide me.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you need to add detail, add it to your original question - https://superuser.com/questions/1556976/laptop-60hz-to-external-monitor-144hz

Comment: deleted previous question.